# how can i fetch header from flat to dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using below code to pickup column name but it printing the first line of data

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, header=1, sep=',')
print (df.columns.values.tolist())
```

Am i missing something here

Answer (score 1):

i think it is zero based. the first line is 0.